# How to integrate the salesforce with php database

Tags: integration

How to integarate and import the data from salesforce to php and from php to salesforce

Comment: Hi @surendra. Welcome to the Salesforce Stackexchange. Glad you decided to join us. Unfortunately, your question is extremely broad. I would suggest reading up on the FAQ to determine what type of questions are valid for this site -http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask. Also, take some time to hear what type of information the community likes to see in questions - http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273/tips-and-tricks-for-asking-a-good-question

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange!

Answer (score 4):

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.1

please refer the above link to understand how to use the Php toolkit.There are good references to start with.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.0_Getting_Started

You will be using partner or enterprise WSDL and then using SOAP API.

Other way would be using REST API of salesforce and using oauth 2.0 as authentication mechanism.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

This resource above may help you

Comment: Would there be any reason not to choose REST API over the PHP Toolkit using SOAP these days?!